# twig - looping same array index result

Tags: php, arrays, twig, symfony-3.4, array-indexing

I am returning array results trough my twig file. I have accessed them but when I render them with "for" I got just first result rendered three times. (number of rows in my db.)

On dump () this is what I get:

[image: Array-result]

I don't know how to acces them all like "foreach".

I tried with [0], because it's the only way it works.

```
 {% for t in field_description.options.transactions %}

         {{ field_description.options.transactions[0].id 

 {% endfor %}
```

So, I need to render 0, 1 and 2 and it returns just 0 three times. Any hints?

Comment: Use `{{ t.id }}` instead of the static index?

Comment: I just got it. Thank you for feedback. @DarkBee